# sg: not found - Alpine Linux

Tags: docker, command, group, alpine-linux, shadow

I am trying to execute a command with a specific user group as described in the linked question ([How to run a process with a specific group?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112225/how-to-run-a-process-with-a-specific-group)) on Alpine Linux, but the system says "not found"

```
~/work $ sg
sh: sg: not found
```

I checked `shadow` package with `apk info -a shadow` and it looks like the `sg` command is present:

```
[...]
cmd:pwunconv
cmd:sg
cmd:su
[...]
```

Reference of `shadow` package on Alpine: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=edge&name=shadow&arch=x86&repo=community

Comment: Is it just not in your PATH? Perhaps in one of the directories of root's path only? Does `sudo sg` work?

Comment: I am using a Docker container. I tried executing `sg` with `root` user and I get tha same error

Comment: Well, according to your link, it should be at `/usr/bin/sg`. What does `ls /usr/bin/sg` give you? If it isn't there, you should probably try reinstalling the package.

Comment: Tried reinstalling the package, it works now! Probably the preinstalled version of the package lacks of some parts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error today with the latest alpine (3.16.0) image. The `sg` command is gone again. I had to switch back to 3.15.4:

```
docker run --rm alpine:3.15.4 sh -c "apk add shadow && sg root -c id"
```

`uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1(bin),2(daemon),3(sys),4(adm),6(disk),10(wheel),11(floppy),20(dialout),26(tape),27(video)`

works, while 3.16.0 does not:

```
docker run --rm alpine:3.16.0 sh -c "apk add shadow && sg root -c id"
```

`sh: sg: not found`

Answer (score 0):

sg migrated to the shadow-login package

```
apk add shadow-login
```

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.16/community/x86_64/shadow-login

You can use this search tool to locate binaries:

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=sg&path=&name=&branch=v3.16&repo=community&arch=x86_64

Answer (score -1):

Alpine Linux is designed to have a very small footprint (it was originally designed for embedded Linux) and all its shell commands are implemented with ["busybox"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox). There are other particularities, such as uncommon libraries, that make it difficult to use for containers.

This said, I wonder why you need to do this in a container, since you can set the id and group of any files when building the container image, run the container with any id.

Comment: I need this to let me access files generated by a script executed inside the container, from the host (files are saved in a volume, owned by group that has same ID in the container and in the host. reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245216/write-in-shared-volumes-docker)

Comment: Not all of Alpine's shell commands are implemented with BusyBox. Many of them are based on the same sources used on other distributions (e.g., if you `apk add openssh`, you get *actual* openssh, not some weird BusyBox version of openssh). 
 If I `apk add shadow` in a local Alpine container, the `sg` command works without a problem.

Comment: @alessionossa You can run the container with a user that has the adequate group id, create user and group with RUN statements in the Dockerfile, and then either use a [USER directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) for the image or  use the `--user` parameter. Both forms let you specify a user:group pair.